# When I deployed django project with nginx+uwsgi, there was always a "502 bad gateway error". What is the reason?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

When I enter my IP in the browser, the page will appear 502 Bad Gateway. Is this my configuration file wrong?
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fefault:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 47.101.157.128:8000;
    }
    location /static{
            alias /var/www/sscc2019/static/;
    }
```

/home/sscc/sscc2019/uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:8000
chdir=home/sscc/sscc2019
wsgi-file=sscc2019/wsgi.py
processes=4
threads=2
master=True
pidfile=uwsgi.pid
daemonize=uswgi.log
module=sscc2019.wsgi:application
vacuum=true
virtualenv=/home/ssccenv
```

Comment: Can you connect to http://47.101.157.128:8000 ?

Comment: If it's on the same system, I'd use 127.0.0.1 for the socket. What's the output of uwsgi?

Comment: I can't connect to 47.101.157.128:8000

Comment: What is in the Nginx error log?